# How do i change a VIM sedcommand to work in a bash script?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, vim, printf

I have a very useful sed command in Vim that I want to put in a simple bashs cript.

But I have tried many variation of it (googled like crazy) but it does not work...

The sed string that works in Vim is:

```
%s/\( \)[0-9]\{8\}$/\=printf(' %08d', line('.'))/g
```

I have tried

```
sed -i "s/\( \)[0-9]\{8\}$/\=printf(' %08d', line('.'))/g"
```

and several variations.

I want to change the 8 last digits in a line (lines van be of different length but they always end with space and 8 digits. Sometimes I need to delete and remove lines, and therefore need to change the sequence number (line number):

Also, I use the same Vim sed command to change words so I can have line number instead. Example:

```
%s/LINENUMB/\=printf('%08d', line('.'))/g
```

Here I want to change word `LINENUMB` with actually 8 digit line number.

It works in Vim but I can't make it work from terminal or in script.

Example 1, I have removed line `00000002`. Now I need to change sequence number:

```
321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321 00000001
6546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546 00000003
987987987987987987987987987987987987987987987987987987987 00000004
```

expected outcome:

```
321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321 00000001
6546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546 00000002
987987987987987987987987987987987987987987987987987987987 00000003
```

Example 2, I want to change `LINENUMB` to actually line number. Let us say it is in line `00206206` in a file:

```
987654321LINENUMB123456789
```

expected outcome:

```
98765432100206206123456789
```

Comment: Few minor nits: `:s` in Vim is not "sed", it's ["substitute"](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:s). `=printf()` is very much [Vim-specific](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-expression), it cannot be used outside of Vim.

Comment: in the 1st example ... will the sequence number always be the same as the line number; in other words, will the first line of the file *always* have a sequence of `00000001`?

Comment: can both scenarios occur within the same file, ie, can a line have the string `LINENUMB` as well as an 8-digit sequence number in the last field of the line?

Comment: @phd, printf is a shell built-in, and works similarly.   line(), OTOH, I think you'd need to track manually in a shell implementation

Comment: This also seems to be begging this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-vim-script-in-a-non-interactive-mode

Comment: @stevesliva `printf` works in shell but `s//\=printf()/` doesn't work in `sed`, the expression `\=` is Vim-specific.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. First line always 00000001 but actually in a header post. See example LINENUMB. Also. LINENUMB only once each line. And yes. They occur in the same file. With VIM I am very good to do what ever with my files. Harder outside. :-)

Comment: @phd  I know.  But for clarity, gnu sed, you could do something like `sed 's/^[0-9]*$/printf "%08d" &/e'`  where `s///e` calls the shell.

Comment: Many many thanks!!! The answer down below with Perl was what i needed. like this :-)
perl -pe 's/( )\d{8}$/sprintf(" %08d",$.)/e' $1 > step1.txt
perl -pe 's/LINENUMB/sprintf("%08d",$.)/ge' step1.txt > step2.txt

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- a file may include both scenarios (8-digit sequence number in last field; literal string `LINENUMB` in the line)
- if `LINENUMB` shows up more than once in a line then each occurrence will be replaced with the same line number
- the first line of the file always starts with sequence `00000001`

Sample data:

```
$ cat raw.dat
321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321 00000001
654654654XLINENUMBX546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546 00000003
          ^^^^^^^^                                               ^^^^^^^^
98798XLINENUMBX9879879879879879XLINENUMBX7987987987987987 00000004
      ^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^^
```

**NOTE:** file does not contain the `^^^^^` lines; these lines are provided to visually highlight strings of interest

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
             { lineno = sprintf("%08d",FNR) }           # zero-pad current line number (FNR)
/LINENUMB/   { gsub(/LINENUMB/,lineno) }                # replace all strings "LINENUMB" with the zero-padded line number
$NF+0 != FNR { $NF = lineno }                           # if last field is not same as current line number then update the field with the zero-padded line number
1                                                       # print current line to stdout
' raw.dat
```

This generates:

```
321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321 00000001
654654654X00000002X546546546546546546546546546546546546546546546 00000002
          ^^^^^^^^                                               ^^^^^^^^
98798X00000003X9879879879879879X00000003X7987987987987987 00000003
      ^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^^
```

---

Once the output is validated as correct there are a couple ways to go about modifying the code to update the original file:

- redirect the output to a temporary/scratch file (eg, `tempfile`) and then `mv tempfile raw.dat`
- if OP is using `GNU awk` with `-i inplace` support then the code can be modified as such: `awk -i inplace '{ lineno = sprintf("%08d",NR) } ...' raw.dat`

Comment: Thanks. Very nice. I will try this also tomorrow to see what fits best to my problem. Kind regards.

Comment: You don't need the first `/LINENUMB/ ` in `/LINENUMB/ { gsub(/LINENUMB/,lineno) }` as that's testing the same regexp twice, all you need is `{ gsub(/LINENUMB/,lineno) }`.

Comment: You should probably change `sprintf("%08d",NR)` to `sprintf("%08d",FNR)` to match the `FNR` you have in `$NF+0 != FNR` and just in case the OP runs it on multiple files at once.

Comment: @EdMorton yeah, I was switching back-n-forth between NR and FNR ... single vs multiple  file ... have gone back to my original ... FNR; thanks

Comment: Actually the thought of multiple files at the same time was my next step. Thanks for insight.

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task, let `file.txt` content be

```
ABLE 00000001
CHARLIE 00000003
DOG 00000004
ZEBRA 00000026
STUFFLINENUMB 00000027
```

then

```
awk '{$NF=sprintf("%08d",NR);gsub(/LINENUMB/,$NF);print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
ABLE 00000001
CHARLIE 00000002
DOG 00000003
ZEBRA 00000004
STUFF00000005 00000005
```

Explantion: I use [`sprintf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to turn number of current line (`NR`) into string with leading zeros of width 8 or greater, then assign it to last field (`NF`), replace all `LINENUMB` with content of last field and `print` that line. **Disclaimer**: I assume your file has fields separated using single space characters. If you want to know more about `NF` or `NR` read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: Thanks. Very neat. In my case there is never a sequence number in the end of a line with LINENUMB. LINENUMB is only in header and trailer posts. Bundles and file trailer kind of. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`perl -pe cmd` is equivalent to `sed cmd`.  It can take stdin from a pipe or a file as input.

Perl, to replace last eight digits with line number:

```
perl -pe 's/\d{8}$/sprintf("%08d",$.)/e' file
```

Perl, to replace LINENUMB with 8-digit line number:

```
perl -pe 's/LINENUMB/sprintf("%08d",$.)/ge' file
```

- The two substitutions can be combined into one invocation of perl, same as sed, with either multiple `-e` or a semicolon separating the two.
- `$.` is the perlvar for "line number".
- `s///e` means you execute a commmand on the replacement side of the substitution for the replacement string.
- `sprintf` vs `printf` in perl is used here because we're printing to a string and not directly to the output stream.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this is what i actually need. Need to learn some perl then. Kind regards. /R

Comment: Maybe.  perl is good if you want shell-like or c-like things to extend your knowledge of sed and grep. OTOH I still think [running vim headless](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-vim-script-in-a-non-interactive-mode) is the quickest way.  Perl is simply the tersest.

Comment: Actually a winner after some lab today... :-) I use this to solve my issue.                perl -pe 's/( )\d{8}$/sprintf(" %08d",$.)/e' $1 > step1.txt
perl -pe 's/LINENUMB/sprintf("%08d",$.)/ge' step1.txt > step2.txt

Comment: Can combine into one step.

Answer (score 0):

These might work for you (GNU sed):

First scenario:

```
 sed = file | sed -E 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*) .*/\2 00000000\1/;s/(.* ).*(.{8})$/\1\2/'
```

Insert a line containing the line number before each line.

Pipe the resulting file into another sed invocation.

In the second sed invocation, fetch two lines and using pattern matching replace the field representing current line number by the new line number prepended with 8 zeroes.

Reduce the new line number field down to 8 digits.

Second scenario:

```
sed  '/LINENUMB/{p;=;d}' file |
sed -E '/LINENUMB/{N;s/\n/&00000000/;s/LINENUMB(.*)\n.*(.{8})$/\2\1/}'
```

Use the same technique as above but adapted for only lines containing `LINENUMB`.

N.B. The second solution assumes that `LINENUMB` is only replaced once per line.

Comment: Thanks. Many cool solutions in this thread.

Comment: Man, `sed =` is limited.  `grep -n ''` is an inline alternative.